# Function not running fully before next execution starts in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 functions I want to run one after the other. For some reason, my first function doesn't fully run when my code is as follows :

```
function main_url_generator_(){
  
  
  create_owner_links_list();
  delete_all_filter_views();
  create_filter_view_w_url();

};
```

When I separate them into 2 functions it works fine:

```
function main_url_generator_1(){
 
  create_owner_links_list();

};



function main_url_generator_2(){
  
  delete_all_filter_views();
  create_filter_view_w_url();


};
```

How can I combine all 3 functions and ensure the first function(`create_owner_links_list()`) has fully run before it goes through the rest of the functions. Please help

Comment: Often the problem that you run into with spreadsheets is that you can write to a spreadsheet and read from it before the spreadsheet has completed filling all of the cells.  In those cases a common solution is to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`;  There may be other issues that would have to be looked at on a case by case basis.  The more you do things like that the better you get.

Comment: If the SpreadsheetApp.flush solution does not work for you then you will be required to submit a [mcve] that will enable us to reproduce the problem so that we can assist you in fixing the problem.

Comment: Here is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) for a simple implementation of `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` for your reference. For us to be able to further help out you can provide the entire script for each of the functions for us to provide a sample fit to your script.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` worked great. I can now  run all three functions in one main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of comments(Thanks all), I modified my function as follows and it works great:

```
function main_url_generator(){
  
  
  create_owner_links_list();
  //Added the SpreadsheetApp.flush function
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  delete_all_filter_views();
  create_filter_view_w_url();

};
```